# How can I solve an exponential equation of the following type?

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

I have an equation of the form 
$$
\frac{a^x}{d_1^x} + \frac{b^{x/2}}{d_2^x} = 1,
$$
which I have already rewritten to
$$
a^xd_2^x+d_1^xb^{x/2}-d_1^xd_2^x = 0.
$$

However, I seem to be stuck here. Howe can I solve this equation for $x$?

In case, that's important: $d_1$ and $d_2$ can be considered constant, while $a$ and $b$ can each be measured multiple times. (Having something like an (overdetermined) equation system in mind).

Comment: I guess that only numerical methods would do it. Could you clarify *Having something like an (overdetermined) equation system in mind* ?

Comment: Guess this was a stupid remark as one equation is sufficient for one unknown. I just meant one could set up the equation several times and carry out something like least squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping that $b>0$, I think it would be simpler to rewrite $$\frac{a^x}{d_1^x} + \frac{b^{x/2}}{d_2^x}= \Big(\frac{a}{d_1}\Big)^x+\Big(\frac{\sqrt b}{d_2}\Big)^x$$ and so the equation to solve is looking like $$c_1^x+c_2^x=1$$ for which there is no analytical solution.

As I said in comments, only numerical methods could solve the problem. The simplest would be Newton which, starting from a *reasonable* guess $x_0$ will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For your problem (as I rewrote it) $$f(x)=c_1^x+c_2^x-1$$ $$f'(x)=c_1^x \log (c_1)+c_2^x \log (c_2)$$

For illustartion purposes, let us use $c_1=2,c_2=3,x_0=0$. The successive iterates will then be generated : $-0.558111$, $-0.765304$, $-0.787654$, $-0.787885$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

**Added later**

This function $$f(x)=c_1^x+c_2^x-1$$ is interesting to solve because its second derivative $$f''(x)=c_1^x \log ^2(c_1)+c_2^x \log ^2(c_2)$$ is always positive. So, at most, the equation has two roots.

Moreover $f(0)=1$ and $f''(0) >0$ which implies that, starting iterations at $x_0=0$, we should always go to the root (if it exists) without any overshoot (as shown in the example above); so the appropriate starting point should be $x_0=-\frac{1}{\log ({c_1 c_2})}$. The first derivative cancels for $$x_*=-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{\log (c_1)}{\log (c_2)}\right)}{\log (c_1)-\log (c_2)}$$ and if $f(x_*) <0$ a second root exists

Comment: Great response, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

$$a^xd_2^x+b^\frac{x}{2}d_1^x-d_1^xd_2^x=0$$

In the general case, the summands on the left-hand side  are algebraically independent. This equation is therefore a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($a^xd_2^x,b^\frac{x}{2}d_1^x,d_1^xd_2^x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to solve the equation by rearranging for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

$$a^xd_2^x+(\sqrt{b})^xd_1^x-d_1^xd_2^x=0$$
$ad_2\to u$, $\sqrt{b}d_1\to v$, $d_1d_2\to w$:
$$u^x+v^x-w^x=0\tag{1}$$

For real $a,b,d_1,d_2,x$, we can transform this equation to a trinomial equation with real exponents:

$x\to\ln(t)$ ($t>0$):
$$t^{\ln(u)}+t^{\ln(v)}-t^{\ln(w)}=0$$

We can transform this equation to the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]:

$$t^{\ln(u)-\ln(w)}+t^{\ln(v)-\ln(w)}-1=0$$
$t\to z^\frac{1}{\ln(u)-\ln(w)}$:
$$z+z^{\frac{\ln(v)-\ln(w)}{\ln(u)-\ln(w)}}-1=0$$

Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.
$\ $

[[Belkić 2019] Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)

[[Szabó 2010] Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)